# youtube slows down in chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, video, youtube

I have a fairly old laptop running Windows 7 32bit.  It is slow but good enough to watch fullscreen videos in media player.  However watching anything on youtube is plain impossible.  It starts fine but after a few minutes (even not fullscreen) gets insanely choppy with CPU utilization sitting at 100% (taken by Chrome).
The system is clean and performs more or less ok otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Chrome to the latest version?

Try emptying caches, editing cookies, and restarting the browser.

Try to view the video in an incognito mode.

Enable Javascript, go to **Settigs**-> **Show advanced settings**-> in the Privacy section click **Content Setting**-> in the Javascript section select **Allow JavaScript to run on all sites (recommended)**. Restart Chrome.

Comment: Incognito mode has the same problem.

Comment: Try removing hardware acceleration, go to Google Chrome's settings and in the search bar search for "hardware" and uncheck if it is present.

Also try to update the [Flash Player](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/?loc=it)

Comment: yeah that didn't help.  I ended up throwing in a small SSD drive and reinstalling windows.  It is better now, but of course i don't know whether it is SSD, clean Windows or slightly different drivers that made the difference.

Comment: Another solution could be to remove all garbage and temporary files, cookies,malware,spyware and the like through a completely free and reliable software, called **SUPERAntispyware**.
These files can cause slowdowns across the computer, especially on the browser.